# /etc/linotp2/ missing after installing LinOTP

Tags: security, ubuntu

After I install LinOTP on a virtualenv and try to proceed to edit the config files, they do not exist nowhere in the system, not even in the /etc/linotp2 folder, which itself doesn't exist either. This folder is in the official docs as being the default folder for LinOTP. Every tutorial I read says that after you install LinOTP this folder should be created, which isn't happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

in case you haven't found the files, yet.
When doing a virtualenv pip install the files will be located at VIRTUALENV-ROOT/etc/linotp2.